# How can I sort an array stating in a given number

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

First of all I am new in php. I need help to sort an array.

I have an array of ID's and zip codes like this:

```
Array (
    [2286] => 3150-259 
    [2284] => 3040-256 
    [2282] => 5430-659 
    [2280] => 2560-270 
    [2278] => 3740-271 
    [2276] => 2495-401 ... and so on 
)
```

Now I have a number lets say '2900' I would like to sort my array from the closest number (2900) to the most distant.

Example: the number is 2900.
So the array should sort like this:

```
Array (
   [2284] => 3040-256 
   [2286] => 3150-259 
   [2280] => 2560-270 
   [2276] => 2495-401 
   [2282] => 5430-659 ... and so on
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: "Closest"? Numerically? Distance? How exactly?

Comment: Can you edit your questions so it contains an example followed by an expected result. It's hard to tell what you want as it is now.

Comment: Closest number, example, the number is 2900. So the array should sort like this:
Array ([2284] => 3040-256 [2282] [2286] => 3150-259 [2284] [2280] => 2560-270 [2276] => 2495-401 [2282] => 5430-659 ...

Comment: I added your comment to the question, but it still doesn't make much sense. Please edit the question, do not put parts of your question in comments.

Comment: Your example makes no sense. You have duplicate indices (`2284` appears twice) and some of them are empty... please try to explain the whole logic behind this. What are you trying to sort on, the first half of the zip code?

Comment: Sorry, editing problems

Comment: I assume you want to look at the first 4 numbers of your zip code, or the numbers before the dash? I also assume you want to *sort numerically*, even though you say "distance"?  How should these get sorted: `3040-256` & `3040-128`? Should the latter come before the first, or does the order not matter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess, you can use function [uksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) in next way:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    2286 => "3150-259",
    2284 => "3040-256",
    2282 => "5430-659",
    2280 => "2560-270",
    2278 => "3740-271",
    2276 => "2495-401",
];

$n = 2900;

uksort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($n) {
    return (abs($a-$n) >= abs($b-$n)) ? 1 : -1;
});

var_export($arr);
```

[Check PHP code here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=f84172519d0ab0b3a4da3eb6233fdccc&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: @Slava Rozhnev It's almost what I want, but instead of sorting the keys I'd like to sort the values :D

Comment: You could simplify the expression with the spaceship operator `return abs($a - $n) <=> abs($b - $n);`.

Comment: @El_Vanja worked like a charm. THAKS YOU SO MUCH

Comment: If you need values, just replace `uksort` with `uasort`.

Comment: Zip codes are not integers, as is assumed in this answer.